# Create list of obstacle locations from a map

Tags: python, beginner

```
map = [
    "......",
    "..##..",
    ".##.#.",
    "...###",
    "###.##",
]

x1 = 0
x2 = 0
obstacle= ()
obstacle = list(obstacle)
j=0

for x,y in enumerate(map):
    x1 = 1
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        if len(y)- 1 == i and y[i] == "#" and y[i-1] == ".":
            x2 = i+1
            x1 = i+1
            obstacle.insert(j,(x1, x2, (x+1)))
            j+=1
        elif len(y)- 1 == i and y[i] == "#":
            x2 = i+1
            obstacle.insert(j,(x1, x2, (x+1)))
            j+=1
        elif len(y)- 1 == i and y[i] == ".":
            break   
        elif y[i] == "#" and y[i+1] == "." and y[i-1] == ".":
            x2 = i+1
            x1 = i+1
            obstacle.insert(j,(x1, x2, (x+1)))
            j+=1
        elif(y[i] == "#" and y[i-1] == "."):
            x1 = i+1
        elif(y[i] == "#" and y[i+1] == "."):
            x2 = i+1
            obstacle.insert(j,(x1, x2, (x+1)))
            j+=1
        
print(obstacle)
```

The program creates a list of obstacle locations, meaning where they begin and end and in which row. This program works as it is supposed to but i am wondering if this code can be more simplified and shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Empty list

```
obstacle= ()
obstacle = list(obstacle)
```

This code creates an empty tuple, and assigns it to `obstacle`.  Then, it takes that empty tuple, and converts it to an empty list, and assigns this new value to `obstacle`.  A Python type checker will see the variable `obstacle` used as both a `tuple` and a `list` and complain that the type mutates.

If the goal is to initialize `obstacle` with an empty list, this can be achieve in one statement:

```
obstacle = []
```

## Append

```
            obstacle.insert(j, …)
            j+=1
```

First, PEP-8 would require a space on either side of the `+=` operator.  But there is no need for the `j` variable at all.  The code is insert values at the end of the obstacle list.  This is simply an `obstacle.append(…)` operation!

## Bug

```
        elif y[i] == "#" and y[i+1] == "." and y[i-1] == ".":
            ...
        elif(y[i] == "#" and y[i-1] == "."):
            ...
```

What happens when `i == 0`?  `y[i-1]` will be `y[-1]` which actually looks at the last character in the row, which is most definitely not the character before `y[0]`!  Does what happens make sense?  The final result being correct for the wrong reasons is bad code.

## Naming

You have `x` (an index), `y` (a string), `i` (an index into `y`), `x1` and `x2` (saved indices into `y`!?!?)

These names make no sense.

You refer to `y` as a “row” in your problem description. Let’s use that as a variable name:

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(map):
    ...
```

You never refer to `x` except as `(x+1)`.  Clearly you want 1-based indexing, so why not use the optional argument of `enumerate` to start at `1`?

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(map, start=1):
    ...
```

Additionally, `map` is a Python function.  While Python doesn’t object to you redefining its identified, it is frowned upon; you should use a different name, like `obstacle_map` to avoid confusion.

## Special cases

You constantly repeat the `len(y)- 1 == i` test.  You could refactor your code into nested `if` statements, to test this only once:

```
        if len(y)- 1 == i:
            if y[i] == "#" and y[i-1] == ".":
                x2 = i+1
                x1 = i+1
                obstacle.insert(j,(x1, x2, (x+1)))
                j+=1
            elif y[i] == "#":
                x2 = i+1
                obstacle.insert(j,(x1, x2, (x+1)))
                j+=1
            elif y[i] == ".":
                break   
        elif y[i] == "#":
            ...
```

But as noted earlier, you probably need `y == 0` special case tests too.  Let’s get rid of the special cases all together:

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(map, start=1):
    row = "." + row + "."
    for ch_idx, ch in enumerate(row):
        if ch == "#":
            ...
```

Since now the row is guaranteed to start with a period and end with a period, a `#` will never occur at the first or last character in the modified `row`, so `ch_idx == 0 or ch_idx == len(row) - 1` is guaranteed to be `False` and never needs to be even checked!

As a bonus, adding the period to the start of the row automatically results in 1-based indices for the original `row`.

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(map, start=1):
    row = "." + row + "."
    for ch_idx, ch in enumerate(row):
        if ch == "#":
            if row[ch_idx - 1] == ".":
                start = ch_idx
            if row[ch_idx + 1] == ".":
                end = ch_idx
                obstacle.append((start, end, row_num))
```

## str.find

Since we’re padding the start and end of each row with a period, an obstacle will always starts with `".#"` and ends with `"#."`.  This means we can use `row.find("#")` to locate the first obstacle’s start, and `row.find("#.")` to locate the first obstacle’s end.  The `str.find()` has an optional argument which will allow the search to start further into the string, so we can use `haystack.find(needle, start)` to locate the first **and** subsequent obstacles start/end points:

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(map, start=1):
    row = "." + row + "."
    start = row.find("#")
    while start >= 0:
        end = row.find("#.", start)
        obstacle.append((start, end, row_num))
        start = row.find("#", end + 1)
```